# Sql match id in another table and join

Tags: mysql, sql

Id fields in `article`, `tweet` are foreign keys to the `posts.post_id`.

In MySQL, I would like to query for example, `post_id=2`.

How do i get the desired result from table `posts + tweet` (since `id=2` only exists in `tweet` table)

```
post_id | author | created_at .... | tweet_id | message     | ... all cols from tweet
2       | B      | ...........     | 2        | Hello world | ...
```

When query `post_id=1`, result will be col from `posts + article`

```
post_id | author | created_at.... | article_id | title | ... all cols from article
1       | A             ..............         | A     | ...
```

Thanks for helping.

---

Database fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be4f302/21

## posts

```
| post_id | author | created_at, modified_at....
|---------|--------|-----------
| 1       | A      | ...
| 2       | B      | ...
| 3       | C      | ...
| 4       | D      | ...
| 5       | E      | ...
```

## article

```
| article_id | title | ...
|------------|-------|----
| 1          | A     | 
| 3          | B     |
```

## tweet

```
| tweet_id | message     | ...
|----------|-------------|---
| 2        | Hello World |
```

Comment: So is the `article_id` and `tweet_id` in the `post` table

Comment: yes. basically `post_id` is the same as `article_id` or `tweet_id`. an id is unique, will not exist in `article` or `tweet` table at the same time, only in one table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query that you can try out..

`SELECT P.*, A.title, T.message 
FROM posts P 
LEFT JOIN article A ON (P.post_id = A.article_id) 
LEFT JOIN tweet T ON (T.tweet_id = P.post_id)`

Hope this helped you.

Comment: Pretty good. Those null fields from another non-relevant table are unavoidable i guess.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63fa85/12 you check the demo here after removing both article tweet with null

Comment: The output is good enough for me. I can remove the irrelevant columns by checking a null `article_id` or `tweet_id` using other scripts. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this right, you might be after a `LEFT JOIN` and `coalesce()`.

```
SELECT p.*,
       coalesce(a.article_id, t.tweet_id) article_id_or_tweet_id,
       coalesce(a.title, t.message) article_title_or_tweet_message
       FROM posts p
            LEFT JOIN article a
                      ON a.article_id = p.post_id
            LEFT JOIN tweet t
                      ON t.tweet_id = p.post_id
       WHERE p.post_id = ?;
```

(Replace the `?` with the ID of the post you want to query.)

Comment: Very close to the desired result. However if there are more columns on `article` and `tweet` I wish I can get them as well (not merged like article_title_or_tweet_message). Is it possible? (updated question)

Comment: @KevinLaw: You can either do the same as with the columns as shown -- put more or less matching ones together in a coalesce -- or get them together and sort out what is what in the application of where ever the results are sent to. Of course you can select a subset of the columns from every table. But you cannot have a dynamic result, that sometimes returns some columns from the one and sometimes from the other table in one query.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use UNION since only one of the SELECT will return a row for a given id

```
SELECT p.*, a.title as 'post'
FROM posts p
JOIN article a ON p.post_id = a.article_id
WHERE p.post_id = 2
UNION 
SELECT p.*, m.message as 'post'
FROM posts p
JOIN tweet t ON p.post_id = t.tweet_id
WHERE p.post_id = 2
```